# Code transformer AST to JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to write js code transformer. I need to parse JS into an AST do some modifications, for example add a new import declaration, and generate JS code back.

Currently I have some troubles with generating JS code. Decorators appear in a wrong place and generator remove brackets around JSX.

I'm new in this area, so probably, I miss some options while transforming/generating code.

**Source code:**

```
// Core
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { actions } from '../../actions/navigation';

const mapStateToProps = ({ navigation }) => ({ // eslint-disable-line arrow-body-style
    menuStatus: navigation.get('menuStatus')
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({ // eslint-disable-line arrow-body-style
    actions: bindActionCreators({ ...actions }, dispatch)
});

@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export default class Home extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <section>
                <h1>Home container!</h1>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

**Parsed/generated code:**

```
// Core
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { actions } from '../../actions/navigation';

const mapStateToProps = ({ navigation }) => ({ // eslint-disable-line arrow-body-style
  menuStatus: navigation.get('menuStatus')
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ // eslint-disable-line arrow-body-style
  actions: bindActionCreators({ ...actions }, dispatch)
});

export default @connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return <section>
                <h1>Home container!</h1>
            </section>;
  }
}
```

[Demo repository](https://github.com/sotream/babylon_test)

Comment: It is a Babel issue, as I stated in the bug you filed: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5335#issuecomment-280829492 We are currently tracking it in https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4585

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Babel bug: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4585

If the expectation is that you want to generate code that could be saved back to the filesystem, you are likely better off looking at [`JSCodeShift`](https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift) since it is targetted at preserving formatting while manipulating code, while Babel has only some interest in existing formatting.